How can I prove that a complex Brownian motion is not pointwise recurrent?

Let $B=B^{(1)}+iB^{(2)}$ be a complex Brownian motion starting from $y\in \mathbb{C}$, i.e. we work under $\mathbb{P}_y$. I want to show that $B$ is not pointwise recurrent which means that it does not returns to a single point $z\in \mathbb{C}$ with probability one. I want to use the conformal invariance theorem.

My idea is the following:
Let $B$ be a complex Brownian motion under $\mathbb{P}_y$ for some $y\in \mathbb{C}$. For simplicity let us first consider the case when $y=0$, so we work under $\mathbb{P}_0$. Consider the holomorphic map $f(z)=e^z$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$. By the conformal invariance theorem part there exists a time change $(\sigma(t))_{t\geq 0}$ such that, $W_t:=f\left(B_{\sigma(t)}\right)=e^{B_{\sigma(t)}}$ is a complex Brownian motion under $\mathbb{P}_{e^{y}}=\mathbb{P}_1$. Since $W$ is a complex Brownian motion under $\mathbb{P}_1$, it takes values in the complex plane, but $t\mapsto W_t$ can never hit the origin, because the exponential function $z\mapsto e^z$ does not take the value $0$. Therefore under $\mathbb{P}_1$, $\mathbb{P}_1\left(\exists~t\geq 0: W_t=0\right)=0$, in particular $$\mathbb{P}_1\left(\exists t>0: W_t=0\right)\leq \mathbb{P}_1\left(\exists~t\geq 0: W_t=0\right)=0,$$ which means that almost surely $W$ does not visit the origin starting from $1$.
My problem is, that I know something about $W$ under $\mathbb{P}_1$, but I would like to deduce something about $B$ under $\mathbb{P}_0$ and then do it for the general case $\mathbb{P}_y$. What I also know is that $B+z$ under $\mathbb{P}_0$ is distributed as $\mathbb{P}_z$ for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$.
Can someone help me how to finish this argument?

@thomaskojar could you maybe help me also here?

You've shown that a complex Brownian motion starting at $1$ doesn't hit $0$ a.s.
For $y\in \mathbb C$, $y\neq0$, could you do the same with the function $z\mapsto ye^z$?
EDIT: Summarising our discussion in chat. What you actually want to prove is that a complex Brownian motion (CBM) started at zero, almost surely does not return to zero (and you should edit your question to say that). Using $z \mapsto e^z$ and conformal invariance we have that CBM started at 1 almost surely does not hit zero. By multiplying by any non-zero $y \in \mathbb C$, a CBM started at any $y \neq0$ also almost surely does not hit zero.
Now let $B$ be a CBM starting at zero. Fix a $T>0$, and we have that $\mathbb P_0[B_T=0]=0$. So, since $(B_{t+T})_t$ is a CBM starting at $B_T$, $(B_{t+T})_t$ almost surely doesn't hit zero i.e. $B$ almost surely does not hit zero after time $T$. But $T>0$ was arbitrary, so it follows that $B$ almost surely does not hit zero after time zero (e.g. take a sequence of positive $T$ decreasing to zero).

Thanks for your answer, but my problem is that I have shown it for $W_t$ which is a brownian motion starting at $1$.  But I need to show it for $B$ so that $B$ is not pointwise recurrent. I don't see how it should help me if I do the same with $z\mapsto ye^z$. Or is it equivalent to show that if $W$ starts from $y$ and it does not hit $y$ a.s. then $B$ starting from $y$ does not hit zero since they have the same distribution?

Yes if $W$ is just a time-change of $B$ then they'll have the same hitting probabilities.

But I mean $W$ is not just a time-change of $B$, because I applied a time change $\sigma(t)$ to $B$ and then the map $z\mapsto e^z$ respectively $z\mapsto ye^z$. So $W$ is a time change of $B$ under a function, why does it then still hold what I said in the first comment or why is your answer of using the function $z\mapsto ye^z$ enough? I mean why can I say something about $B$ if I have only proofed it for $W$?

Yes my previous comment wasn't quite accurate. $W$ and $B$ are both complex brownian motions, so if you prove a hitting probability result for $W$ starting from $p$, it also applies to $B$ starting from $p$.

Mhhh sorry I still do not get it. I have shown that $W$ starting from $1$ does not hit $0$, due to your comment I should then have that $B$ starting at $1$ does not hit $0$ but I would like to have $B$ starting at zero therefore I took $y=0$ in the first case. Where is my error?

By translating and scaling the 1->0 result above, you can show that a compact Brownian motion started at any point $y$ does not hit any other point $z\neq y$. And $0$ is certainly included in that. Is there anything left to prove?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

can we discuss it in chat because this seems a bit weird to me. So I can explain everything in more detail.

I have asked some further question in the chat can you help me with them?
